# Google analytics App + Web slow send collect request

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am trying to implement GTM and new Google analytics web + app and I can see its taking 5sec to push data to google analytics.
I have tested with a fresh site and simple tracking event on click in link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ILJLROq05OQwx3oXXCrOVXDeoxtbdKVw/view?usp=sharing

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
// If the clicked element doesn't have the right selector, bail
if (!event.target.matches('.btn-GA')) return;
// Don't follow the link
event.preventDefault();
// Log the clicked element in the console
console.log('Click......');
dataLayer.push({
"event": "wa_trigger",
"wa_event": "bounce_out",
"wa_action": "bounce_action",
"wa_label": "bounce_label"
});
}, false);

<a class="btn-GA" href="#">TEST CLICK</a>
```

================================================

## UPDATE::::

Thanks for your answer. I noticed its really fast if I set true for the GA debug https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna  and the hit comes fast and first others hit.. but when its off the hit comes at then end after 5sec.

And here screenshot from console:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4n1WldESjbwTYkwiQ9PPX9RijigDApt/view?usp=sharing

Here the push and hit
Here push =====>

```
a.js:6      Google - dataLayer.push():  event: wa_trigger
a.js:6 ~ Object: 
{
    event: "wa_trigger",
    wa_event: "logo-click"
}
Currently in memory:  {event: "wa_trigger", wa_event: "logo-click", eventCallback: ƒ}
a.js:6 ~ Call Stack
a.js:6 ~ 20.140 s since Document Start
```

And here the hit: ====>

```
~ Data:  {
    events: [
        {
            en: "-logo-click",
            _et: "2258",
            ep.transport: "beacon"
        },
        {
            en: "page_view",
            _et: "36",
            ep.transport: "beacon"
        }
    ],
    v: "2",
    tid: "G-xxxxxx",
    gtm: "xxxx",
    _p: "109194814",
    sr: "1440x900",
    ul: "sv-se",
    cid: "2129079382.1587074095",
    dl: "http://www.site.lo/",
    dr: "",
    dt: "Site title",
    sid: "1587312754",
    sct: "5",
    seg: "1",
    _s: "2",
    statusCode: 204
}
~ Network Hit:  {frameId: 0, fromCache: false, initiator: "http://www.site.lo", ip: "216.58.207.206", method: "POST", …}
dlc.js:1208 ~ 26.208s since Document Start
dlc.js:1208 ~ 4.316s since last hit
```

Comment: Hi,
Your code does a dataLayer.push(), which is good.
Can you show in the console WHEN does the push happen compared to when the hit is being sent ?
You can use https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adswerve-datalayer-inspec/kmcbdogdandhihllalknlcjfpdjcleom for example for that
Or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dataslayer/ikbablmmjldhamhcldjjigniffkkjgpo

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer.

Comment: It could be related to the built-in Enhanced measurement
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9216061
Did you enable it in the GUI ?
It could interfere with your own way of capturing clics

Comment: I dont think its Enhanced meas. I disabled it all and same problem.. Well, I know the data is batched and thats why there is delay like 5sec.. But I need to force datalayer to send the data to google server somehow..
https://support.google.com/tagmanager/thread/39994241?hl=en

Comment: Can you come back to my first proposal: to debug how fast dataLayer.push events are being sent compared to GA hits being sent
The GA debugger extensions only shows GA calls, it doesn't allow to audit the whole process.

Or did you try the GTM preview & debug mode ?

Comment: Hi @OpenSEO, I added that in the update. Yes I tried GTM preview and debug the push comes fast, but the hit delay 5sec..   If there is a better way I can send you the site if you could help me and check it. if u could and have time to talk online. maybe skype. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, can you update the question Title to "App + Web" instead of "Web + App" ? to match the official name :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I did my best to fix the issue and I used fetch to send the data directly to google server and skip the dataLayer and by using Callback function and a bit delay 1sec to wait for GA to be loaded.
Here how I did it and I am not sure if this is the best way or not but its working 100% and I got exact data on both old and old data.
BounceOut is the old data GA1
Bounce_out and Bounce_out_source is the new one GA2

```
 trackAndBounceOut(url, callback) {

        var action = this.state.bouncer.meta.partnerName
        var label = this.state.bouncerId
        var type = Session.page
        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || []

        var checkGA
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (ga && typeof ga.getAll == 'function') {
                checkGA = true
            } else {
                checkGA = false
            }

            if (checkGA) {
                var clientId = ga.getAll()[0].get('clientId');
                var adSenseId = ga.getAll()[0].get('adSenseId')
                var screenResolution = ga.getAll()[0].get('screenResolution')
                var userLanguage = ga.getAll()[0].get('language')
                var docReferrer = ga.getAll()[0].get('referrer')
                var docLocation = ga.getAll()[0].get('location')
                var debug = false       // Enable for debug!!
                var doctTitle = document.title

                var stringUrlData = {
                    v: 2,
                    tid: 'G-XXXXXXXXXX',
                    gtm: 'XXXXXX',
                    _p: adSenseId,
                    sr: screenResolution,
                    ul: userLanguage,
                    cid: clientId,
                    dl: docLocation,
                    dr: docReferrer,
                    dt: doctTitle,
                    _dbg: debug ? 1 : '',
                }

                var urlString = Object.keys(stringUrlData)
                    .filter(analyticsKey => stringUrlData[analyticsKey])
                    .map(analyticsKey => analyticsKey + '=' + encodeURIComponent(stringUrlData[analyticsKey]))
                    .join('&')

                var bounce_out = 'en=Bounce_Out&ep.Action=' + action
                var bounce_out_source = 'en=Bounce_Out_source&ep.Action=' + type + '_' + action + '&ep.Label=' + type

                fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?' + urlString + '&' + bounce_out, { method: 'POST' })
                fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?' + urlString + '&' + bounce_out_source, { method: 'POST' })

                if (Session.page == 'Partner') {
                    window.dataLayer.push(
                        { 'event': 'pageEvent', 'Category': 'Partner page', 'action': 'Bounce Out', 'label': Session.page + '_' + action },
                    )

                    var partner_bounce_out = 'en=Partner_bounce-out&ep.Action=' + action
                    fetch('https://www.google-analytics.com/g/collect?' + urlString + '&' + partner_bounce_out, { method: 'POST' })
                }
            }

            callback(action, type, label, url)
        }.bind(this), 1000);
    }

    trackAndBounceOutRedirect(action, type, label, url) {
        window.dataLayer.push(
            {
                'event': 'bounceOut',
                'action': action,
                'label': type + '_' + label,
                'eventCallback': () => {
                            window.location.href = url
                },
                'eventTimeout': 1000
            }
        )
    }

   // And here then we call the main function and send the callback one:
        this.trackAndBounceOut(this.state.bouncer.url, this.trackAndBounceOutRedirect)
```

Comment: you should edit your initial question instead of adding feedback through an answer... Since it is not a solution...

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be "by design":

> One thing you might have noticed is the delay it takes for the hit to
>   be sent. When you load the page, you can see how the browser waits a
>   few seconds before dispatching the hit to GA. This is because GAv2
>   batches requests automatically, which, again, is a great feature
>   upgrade.
>   One thing you might have noticed is the delay it takes for the hit to
>   be sent. When you load the page, you can see how the browser waits a
>   few seconds before dispatching the hit to GA. This is because **GAv2
>   batches requests automatically**, which, again, is a great feature
>   upgrade.
>
> By batching multiple hits into a single request, browser resources are
>   saved for other things. The delay is due to the browser waiting to see
>   if other hits should be dispatched together with the Page View.

https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/getting-started-with-google-analytics-app-web/

Be confident that the hit will fire before the user leaves the page !

Comment: Yes and I can see that.. but Again I have redirect after data.push and I am lossing data when I have GA2 but I am getting that data on the old GA.

Comment: @MohammedAlasaad could you nail down in which situations you are loosing data and how much volume in % it represents ? It shouldn't. Can you check in the Console or Network panel with the Preserve log option ticked ?

Comment: I have checked that and Its not sent to google as I have redirect after push. I still have the Old GA and the new GA2 and pushing to both.. All other events works but not the one after redirect. I can show you that If you want connect to my pc remote.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot with preserve log enabled showing the data loss ?
Looks like it would be applicable to open a bug report here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187400

Comment: Yes I already did that.. check the update in the question.. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1a4n1WldESjbwTYkwiQ9PPX9RijigDApt/view?usp=sharing .. I think dataLayer should has some trigger or force to tell it push data to google server.. Thats best way if we will use batching and thats need to wait 5sec

Comment: Here the bug link https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154434606

Comment: @MohammedAlasaad would you have a sample running page somewhere demonstrating the issue ? (without your fix) I managed to get someone in the GA team to look at it but the easier it is to demonstrate the issue, the better it will be handled. Can you add info on  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154434606 ? Many thanks !

Comment: @MohammedAlasaad would you also please explicit the share of loss in data and the volume of data you expected ? like 10% of the events were missing, corresponding to 5000 events a day ? Or is it 2 events out of 10 ? Thanks

Comment: Hi @open-seo, Yes Its a lot missing data.  For example new GA has 1,073 VS old GA  2,258 in a day... I will write there as well in issuetracker. Thanks